# Why am I 1px out with my list elements?

Tags: html, css, layout

trying to reproduce the header [here](http://www.urlgone.com/87f271/), and so far i have this http://www.webdevout.net/test?0A. I can't figure out why the text containers extend out below the bottom of the bar by 1px, and why they dont on the other site.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i have fixed it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/HZLC4/1/

i removed the width of wrapper to fit in JSFiddle's display. you can add it back.

tips to note though:

- reset always comes first
- to have friendly links, pad the links. makes the links have bigger "box" to click on
- padding links and text adds height to the parent container so you wont have to declare height for the wrapper.
- divs autofit to content if it has no dimensions declared.  it means divs autofit the links and text resulting in to no more "1px problem"
- i forgot, for link padding to take effect, `<a>` must be styled with `display:block`

Answer (score 2):

You set line-height for .header h1 to 11px, but actually you need only 10px.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the header styling:

```
header li, header h1 { 
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 11px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #2d2d2d;
    border-right: 1px solid #333;
}
```

padding-top 20px + padding-bottom 20px + line-height 11px = 51px

Either you need to increase the height of the header to 51px, or you need to decrease either padding or line-height.

Answer (score 1):

Dont know if you can see it.

But i changed line-height from 11 to 10 on
header li, header h1 {

And that worked.